# My addZipcode function is not showing the new value in the template view in my Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

In my Angular 2 app I am setting up a component that lists zipcodes, and I want the user to be able to both delete and add zipcodes to the list. The delete function is working as desired. But the addZipcode method, which uses a push method, is adding an icon representing the new listing below the existing list, but there is no actual value showing up there.

This is relevant code I have in my component (edited for brevity):

```
export class LocationsComponent implements OnInit {

  zipcode;
  addZipInput = false;
  newZipcode;

  zipcodes = [
    { zipcode: '94101' },
    { zipcode: '94105' },
    { zipcode: '94110' },
    { zipcode: '94115' },
    { zipcode: '94119' }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.newZipcode = '';
  }

  deleteZip(zipIndex: number) {
    this.zipcodes.splice(zipIndex, 1);
  }


  addZipcode(event) {
    this.zipcodes.push(this.newZipcode);
    this.newZipcode = '';
    this.addZipInput = false;
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  addZipClicked() {
    this.addZipInput = !this.addZipInput;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

... And here's what I have in my component template view:

```
<div class="page-section">

        <div class="header">Treatment Locations<span class="add-location" (click)="addZipClicked()"><i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>Add Location</span></div>

      <div *ngIf="addZipInput">
        <!--<input placeholder="Zipcode to Add" autofocus>
        <button md-raised-button [(ngModel)]="newItem" (click)="addZip()">Add</button>
      </div>-->
        <form (submit)="addZipcode($event)">
        <input [(ngModel)]="newZipcode" class="textfield" name="newZipcode">
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      </div>
        <div class="section-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div *ngFor="let zipcode of zipcodes; let myIndex=index">{{zipcode.zipcode}}<span class="delete-option" (click)="deleteZip(myIndex)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, very specifically, it's the addZipcode function I'm trying to get to work. Again, this is what I currently have:

```
  addZipcode(event) {
    this.zipcodes.push(this.newZipcode);
    this.newZipcode = '';
    this.addZipInput = false;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: What does `this.newZipcode` look like just before you push it? Can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newZipcode));` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert `object` instead of `string` so replace

```
this.zipcodes.push(this.newZipcode);
```

with

```
this.zipcodes.push({ zipcode: this.newZipcode });
```

Comment: My API is down right now, but I will test this solution as soon as I can. It looks right to me, though. Thanks.